# mySQL concat if null drop literal

Tags: php, mysql, concatenation

I have a mySQL database that I am trying to get data from.

Here is my query:

```
"SELECT booking_number, customer_name, passenger_name, 
contact_phone, CONCAT(unit_number,'/', street_number, ' ', street_name, ', ', suburb) AS pickup_address, destination_suburb, pickup_datetime FROM $sql_table
```

If unit number is null I need to remove the literal '/'.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

use it like this

```
CONCAT(unit_number, IF(unit_number IS NULL, '', '/'),street_number,.........
```